# TensorFlow: Thread safety of class member when adding a new Op

Tags: thread-safety, tensorflow

I'm confused about when it is necessary to consider the issue of thread safety when writing a new Op.

In TensorFlow's [How-to add a new op guide,](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/#implement_the_kernel_for_the_op) I read below sentence which reminds users to add a mutex to prevent data race.

> Important note: Instances of your OpKernel may be accessed concurrently. Your Compute method must be thread-safe. Guard any
>   access to class members with a mutex (Or better yet, don't share state
>   via class members! Consider using a ResourceMgr to keep track of Op
>   state).

However, in the followed text in the same web page about [how to add attr to op,](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/#op_registration) I found the class member `int preserve_index_;` is not protected by mutex in the given code snippet:

```
class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {
    // Get the index of the value to preserve
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context,
                   context->GetAttr("preserve_index", &preserve_index_));
    // Check that preserve_index is positive
    OP_REQUIRES(context, preserve_index_ >= 0,
                errors::InvalidArgument("Need preserve_index >= 0, got ",
                                        preserve_index_));
  }
  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // ...
  }
 private:
  int preserve_index_;
};
```

So, is there any implicit mechanism in TensorFlow to protect the variable named "preserve_index_" from data racing? If yes, could you please tell me the location of corresponding codes which ensures the thread safety of this variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the documentation says that the "Compute" method must be thread-safe.  A mutex would be needed if in the Compute function of the OpKernel, the variable was being modified, since multiple threads can call Compute() on the same OpKernel object.

In this example, preserve_index_ is a member variable that is set during construction of the OpKernel, not the Compute method. An object's constructor will only be accessed from one thread (the thread creating that unique object), so there is no need to protect that variable.  The object is then read-only afterwards in Compute(), so no mutex is needed.

Comment: Under what condition can multi-thread access the same object's Compute method??